# Elution from an Ion Exchange Column

Tags: chemical-engineering, waste-water-treatment, columns

I am using concentrated NaCl(10%) to elute Cobalt (II) ions from a cationic exchange column. How would I determine the volumetric flowrate of regenerant needed to completely elute the cobalt ions from the resin?

Answer (score 0):

If you have lab data that tells you how long it takes for the Co(II) to be eluted, you can scale up keeping the residence time the same (and then add is some margin for slower mass transfer at the larger scale).

Flow rate can't be too fast otherwise the capacity and resolution of the elution will be low and you can damage the column beads. You can go slow, but you sacrifice column up-time.